# Get the running count of an object in TableView in a column

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have two types of Objects in a table, for simplicity, I will call them Dog and Cat, both of these objects extend from Animal. I am attempting to have a running count of the objects. For the moment I will focus on the Dog object.

I have a TableColumn that I've created a value factory for, and it looks like this:

```
column.setCellFactory(callback -> new TableCell<>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(!empty) {
            if (getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()) instanceof Dog) {
                int count = setDogCount(getTableView(), getIndex(), 0);
                setText(String.valueOf(count));
            } else {
                setText("");
            }
        } else {
            setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

The recursive method I use is here:

```
private int setDogCount(TableView<Animal> table, int index, int count){
    if(index == 0){
        if(table.getItems().get(index) instanceof Dog) {
            return count + 1;
        } else {
            return count;
        }
    }
    if(table.getItems().get(index) instanceof Dog){
        return setDogCount(table, --index, ++count);
    }else {
        return setDogCount(table, --index, count);
    }
}
```

This actually works about 95% of the time. The only times it breaks is when some sorts occur. It breaks because cell factories are only called when they are sorted, so if a sort does not occur, then it won't update the count. This leads to some multiple counts of Dog depending on the circumstances.

> QUESTION:

So, is there a way to have it update only one column on sort? I would like to try to avoid refreshing the entire table, and I was hoping there is a better way.

Thanks!

Edit:
By "if a sort does not occur" I mean that if that object was not moved from its current index, it does not call the cell factory.

Edit 2:
Here is a picture to see what I am facing.

Before Sorting -> After Sorting:

[image: Before sorting]
[image: After sorting]

As you can see, index 0 switched with index 3, thus changing the count column appropriately, but now I have no number 1, and two number 3s. This is because it only updates the rows that were switched.

Edit 3:
Here is the small application to see the changes. When you run it, please click on the Commands Known column once to see what I am up against.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TableView<Animal> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Animal, String> count = new TableColumn<>("Count");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> sound = new TableColumn<>("Sound");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> commandsKnown = new TableColumn<>("Commands Known");
        table.getColumns().addAll(count, name, sound, commandsKnown);
        root.setCenter(table);

        count.setCellFactory(callback -> new TableCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    if (getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()) instanceof Dog) {
                        int count = setDogCount(getTableView(), getIndex(), 0);
                        setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    } else {
                        setText("");
                    }
                } else {
                    setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        name.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().nameProperty());
        sound.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().soundProperty());
        commandsKnown.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
            if(data.getValue() instanceof Dog){
                return ((Dog) data.getValue()).commandsKnownProperty();
            }
            return new SimpleStringProperty("");
        });

        ObservableList<Animal> animals = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        animals.add(new Dog("Tweeter", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake, drop"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Sub Woofer", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake"));
        animals.add(new Cat("Kitter Cat", "Meow"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Bass", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake, fetch"));

        table.setItems(animals);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private int setDogCount(TableView<Animal> table, int index, int count){
        if(index == 0){
            if(table.getItems().get(index) instanceof Dog) {
                return count + 1;
            } else {
                return count;
            }
        }
        if(table.getItems().get(index) instanceof Dog){
            return setDogCount(table, --index, ++count);
        }else {
            return setDogCount(table, --index, count);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class Animal{
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty sound = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public String getSound() {
            return sound.get();
        }

        public StringProperty soundProperty() {
            return sound;
        }

        public void setSound(String sound) {
            this.sound.set(sound);
        }
    }

    public class Dog extends Animal{
        StringProperty commandsKnown = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Dog(String name, String sound, String commandsKnown){
            setName(name);
            setSound(sound);
            setCommandsKnown(commandsKnown);
        }

        public String getCommandsKnown() {
            return commandsKnown.get();
        }

        public StringProperty commandsKnownProperty() {
            return commandsKnown;
        }

        public void setCommandsKnown(String commandsKnown) {
            this.commandsKnown.set(commandsKnown);
        }
    }

    public class Cat extends Animal{

        public Cat(String name, String sound){
            setName(name);
            setSound(sound);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need a count of objects, just iterate thru and count the objects.sorting shouldn't change the number of the objects. is there a reason you feel you need to count while sorting?

Comment: @mavriksc I need the running count of each type in a column. So if index 1 is a Dog, then a 1 is shown, if index 2 is a Cat, nothing is shown, if index 3 is a Dog, a 2 is shown. This breaks down when sorting, because some indexes wont sort and thus recalculate the running count. So I could have duplicate numbers. I will update my question with a picture showing what occurs.

Comment: @mavriksc Updated question with pictures.

Comment: is column 1 a count of objects of that type. or just an index. in the images you have before-> after (wrong) can you show after(right).seems like you just want a numbered list.

Comment: Is this `JavaFX`?

Comment: @mavriksc count of objects for that type.

Comment: @Sedrick yes, Javafx

Comment: in your example could you use names of dogs and cats so we can tell more about what is going on. i don't know who those people are or what their type is. would there. is this in response to pressing a sorting button or in response to adding something to the list.

Comment: This is just a guess here, but I don't think this should be done in your `cellfactory`. How does your `List<object>` look? I think when you add a new `Object` to the `TableView`, you should do your count using your `List`. Example `int count = listView.getItems().filtered((t) -> {
            return t instanceof Dog;
        }).size();`

Comment: @Sedrick the `List<Animal>` is populated before hand. I sadly have to have both `Cat` and `Dog` in the table. The problem is not the initial count, but rather when I click on a table header to sort, it does not update all indicies, but rather only those that need to be sorted reaulting in duplicate/missing count. I am a terrible explainer, so if anything doesnt make sense let me know.

Comment: Create a small app that shows your current problem and post it.

Comment: @Sedrick. I was hoping to avoid that, but I can and will when I get back to my computer tomorrow. I will also include comments in the code so everyone can follow along. I will update my question and tag you when it is done.

Comment: a cell definitely is the wrong place to change the data (even if it's meta) ... do it in the model ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Sadly I'm not allowed to add this field to the model.

Comment: @Sedrick Updated the question with the small application.

Comment: What are we counting here?

Comment: @Sedrick Running count of the Dogs.

Comment: What do you mean by running count? Will all the dogs have the same number or the number increments everything a new Dog entry is added?

Comment: The Number increments with each Dog. The first Dog will have a 1, the next a 2, etc.. All Cats will have no number.

Comment: In my answer, I will present a new approach.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on my comment:

> a cell definitely is the wrong place to change the data (even if it's
>   meta) ... do it in the model ;)

As model I meant not only your data object/list but also all state that is related to the data, even if it's also related to the view, as f.i. a running counter. You must model that relation somehow outside of the view.

Below is an example that models the relation by an additional list for the counters, one property per owner. It's the task of the app to keep it in sync with the owners as shown in the table whenever anything that effects the counters changes (f.i. when the list is sorted or the pet changed or anything).

The code:

```
public class TableWithExternalCounterSO extends Application {

    /**
     * Updates the counter data from the given source list, assuming that
     * both have the same size (if that's not true, adjust counter size
     * as needed)
     */
    private void updateDogCounterFrom(ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Integer>> dogCounter, 
            ObservableList<? extends PetOwner> owners) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < owners.size(); i++) {
            PetOwner owner = owners.get(i);
            if (owner.petProperty().get() == Pet.DOG) {
                dogCounter.get(i).set(++count);
            } else {
                dogCounter.get(i).set(-1);
            }
        }    
    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        // the base data
        ObservableList<PetOwner> owners = PetOwner.owners();
        // a list for the counters, that must be kept in sync with changes in the table
        ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Integer>> dogCounter = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        owners.forEach(owner -> dogCounter.add(new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(-1)));
        // initial sync
        updateDogCounterFrom(dogCounter, owners);

        SortedList<PetOwner> sorted = new SortedList<>(owners);
        sorted.addListener((ListChangeListener<? super PetOwner>) c -> {
            // sync after change
            updateDogCounterFrom(dogCounter, c.getList());
        });
        TableView<PetOwner> table = new TableView<>(sorted);
        sorted.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());

        TableColumn<PetOwner, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        TableColumn<PetOwner, Pet> pet = new TableColumn<>("Pet");
        pet.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pet"));
        TableColumn<PetOwner, Integer> dogIndex = new TableColumn<>("Running Dog#");
        dogIndex.setSortable(false);
        dogIndex.setCellValueFactory(cd -> {
            // astonishingly, this is called for every cell after sorting, 
            // that is all cells are newly created
            int index = cd.getTableView().getItems().indexOf(cd.getValue());
            return dogCounter.get(index);
        });
        dogIndex.setCellFactory(cb -> {
            return new TableCell<PetOwner, Integer>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty || item != null && item.intValue() < 0) {
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(String.valueOf(item));
                    }
                }

            };
        });

        table.getColumns().addAll(name, pet, dogIndex);
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(table);
        return pane;
    }

    private enum Pet {
        CAT, DOG
    }

    public static class PetOwner {
        ObjectProperty<Pet> pet;
        StringProperty name;

        PetOwner(String name, Pet pet) {
            this.pet = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "pet", pet);
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", name);
        }

        public ObjectProperty<Pet> petProperty() {
            return pet;
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public static ObservableList<PetOwner> owners() {
            ObservableList<PetOwner> owners = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                owners.add(new PetOwner("O "  + i, i % 3 == 0 ? Pet.CAT : Pet.DOG) );
            }
            return owners;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name.get( ) + " " + pet.get();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a `static` variable to keep up with the `Dog's` ID.

Example code below:

> Full Code:

**Dog Class**

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Dog extends Animal
{

    static int dogCounter = 0;

    private String commnads;
    private final int dogId;

    public Dog(String name, String sound, String commands)
    {
        super(name, sound);
        this.commnads = commands;
        dogId = ++dogCounter;
    }

    public String getCommnads()
    {
        return commnads;
    }

    public void setCommnads(String commnads)
    {
        this.commnads = commnads;
    }

    public int getDogId()
    {
        return dogId;
    }

}
```

**Cat Class**

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */

public class Cat extends Animal
{

    public Cat(String name, String sound)
    {
        super(name, sound);
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TableView<Animal> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Animal, String> count = new TableColumn<>("Count");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> sound = new TableColumn<>("Sound");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> commandsKnown = new TableColumn<>("Commands Known");
        table.getColumns().addAll(count, name, sound, commandsKnown);
        root.setCenter(table);

        count.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("dogId"));
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
        sound.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("sound"));
        commandsKnown.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("commands"));

        ObservableList<Animal> animals = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        animals.add(new Dog("Tweeter", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake, drop"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Sub Woofer", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake"));
        animals.add(new Cat("Kitter Cat", "Meow"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Bass", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake, fetch"));

        table.setItems(animals);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private int setDogCount(TableView<Animal> table, int index, int count)
    {
        if (index == 0) {
            if (table.getItems().get(index) instanceof Dog) {
                return count + 1;
            }
            else {
                return count;
            }
        }
        if (table.getItems().get(index) instanceof Dog) {
            return setDogCount(table, --index, ++count);
        }
        else {
            return setDogCount(table, --index, count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

**SortedList code:**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TableView<Animal> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Animal, String> count = new TableColumn<>("Count");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> sound = new TableColumn<>("Sound");
        TableColumn<Animal, String> commandsKnown = new TableColumn<>("Commands Known");
        table.getColumns().addAll(count, name, sound, commandsKnown);
        root.setCenter(table);


        count.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("dogId"));
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
        sound.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("sound"));
        commandsKnown.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("commands"));

        ObservableList<Animal> animals = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        animals.add(new Dog("Tweeter", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake, drop"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Sub Woofer", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake"));
        animals.add(new Cat("Kitter Cat", "Meow"));
        animals.add(new Cat("Kitter Cat 2", "Meow"));
        animals.add(new Dog("Bass", "Woof", "Sit, rollover, shake, fetch"));

        SortedList<Animal> sortedList = new SortedList(animals);
        Comparator<Animal> comparator = (c, d) -> {
            if (c instanceof Cat && d instanceof Dog) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (c instanceof Dog && d instanceof Cat) {
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        };

        comparator.thenComparing((c, d) -> {
            if (c instanceof Cat && d instanceof Dog) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (c instanceof Dog && d instanceof Cat) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                if (c instanceof Cat && d instanceof Cat) {
                    return c.getName().compareTo(d.getName());
                }
                else {
                    Dog tempDog1 = (Dog) c;
                    Dog tempDog2 = (Dog) d;

                    if (tempDog1.getDogId() > tempDog2.getDogId()) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }

                return 0;
            }
        });
        sortedList.setComparator(comparator);

        table.setItems(sortedList);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not intended behavior. If you sort by Name, the numbers are no longer in order. They must stay in order for every sort, no matter how the data is changed.

Comment: That's a different problem.

Comment: There are plenty of topics on how to sort a TableView. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Comment: Please see updated question. I added a Question blockquotes to better identify what I was trying to ask.

Comment: If you select count column then press Shift and press Name column once or twice, the sort should be as you want it.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807414/sort-javafx-table-on-multiple-columns

Comment: your sortedList comparator looks fishy, in not being bound to the table's .. (didn't run your example, though)